# Always display the first few lines of a buffer in Vim

Tags: vim

I often use gVim and Vim to view data tables in which the top row is the header. Is there any way to display this top row while browsing through the rest of the table? Ditto columns for the case in which the first column is a row heading.

**EDIT:** I accepted a good answer (and there were others) for showing the top column.

The horizontal (first row) equivalent to the answer I accepted is

```
:vert split
ctrl+w 5 |
```

or

```
ctrl+w v
ctrl+w 10 |
```

It would be nice to be able to do both, but apparently that is not straightforward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could open the file in two windows (command line: `vim -o file file`, or `ctrl+w n :o file`) and then one is fixed and you can scroll in the other window.

If you want to see the first 5 rows press `ctrl+w 5 _`.

Comment: An easier way to open the same file(buffer) in two windows would be to split the window using `Ctrl+W S`

Comment: or just type `:sp` to split the window.

Answer (score 5):

If you're working with datatables alot, you might want to take a look at the [csv plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2830). it has the `:HeaderToggle` command that does exactly what you want, and many more commands that you might find useful.

Comment: Great tip, that's very helpful.  I also use tab and space delimited files, and this link had great advice on how to deal with those: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Mode-for-tab-delimited-files-td1161575.html.  In particular, you can change the CSV plugin's delimiter with `:let g:csv_delim=" *"` and load the file as a csv with `:set filetype=csv`

Answer (score 2):

In this case it is convenient to use the preview window (see
`:help preview-window`). To open the preview window showing the first, say,
eight lines of the current file, issue the following commands.

```
:set previewheight=8
:pedit +1
```

Use the `:pclose` command (`:pc`, for short)
or the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd> shortcut
to close the preview window.

Comment: The preview window doesn't seem to default to scrollbind on.  Is there any advantage to preview over a simple split?

Comment: @keflavich:  According to the question's description, you want to always see the first lines of a file while viewing/editing the rest of it.  The preview window in this solution is opened to show the first few lines while you are free to edit in the original window.  So, why do you want to `scrollbind` these windows?  Regarding to the advantages of the preview window.  There are two major ones: (1) it is easy to open and close the preview window without loosing the focus and switching between the windows, (2) the preview window is configured to maintain its size and position by default.

Comment: That's helpful.  The reason I want scrollbind on is that the width of the table can be wider than the vim window; I want horizontal scrollbind so that I can continue to see headings scrolling right and left.

Answer (score 1):

See http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Excel-like-quot-freeze-panels-quot-feature-in-vim-td1178008.html for some good ways to show leading rows or leading columns (though not easily both at once, unfortunately).